# Tilt car to accomodate for larger Tire

Tags: unity, c#, mathematics, rotation, vector

I would like to rotate the car so that the front wheels are touching the ground without using physics.

[image: The Back tires are on the floor but the front are not]

As you can see i want to rotate the car by angle a, but making sure that both tires are touching the floor. but it is kind of hard as the centre mass of the wheels is not the back of the car.

Comment: What information do you have? Do you have the distance of the axis` and the radius of the wheels? If so, this becomes a trigonometry puzzle.

Comment: whatif the ground is not even ?

Comment: the ground is always even.